# Is it possible to embedd compiler inside browser

Tags: c++, c, browser, compiler-construction

I have in site topcoder.com where we can create and compile code in the browser.

is it possible to code something like that in my browser i can write code in text editor and then i have compile button over there.

Or may be the request is sent to the compiler on server gcc and then get result from there.

How can i achieve something like that

Comment: An entire Linux emulator has been written in JavaScript, and it can compile and run C programs in the browser, on the client side: http://bellard.org/jslinux/

Comment: Also, it might be possible to compile a C compiler's souce code to JavaScript using Emscripten: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten

Answer (score 3):

Your latter (send to server) is exactly what sites like [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) do. There are of course security problems with openly allowing people to execute compilers and run programs on your server.

The browser only option could include:

- NaCl (native client)
- Writing a compiler in JS (possible, not suggested for sanity depending on language)
- Using a Java applet and writing a compiler
- Ditto for Flash
- Ditto for SIlverlight
- ActiveX control (not suggested)

Comment: Considering you have a Java-to-JS compiler, and a Java compiler written in Java, it seems quite possible to produce a Java compiler in Javascript.

Comment: You can run the compiler in a virtual machine or sandbox. That case it won't create any side effects in the server

Answer (score 2):

Sites like TopCoder have the compiler on a back-end server.  The code pasted to the site is sent to back-end server where it is compiled and run and the results returned to the user's browser.

Comment: Are there ready to use libraries for sending code to server  in python

Comment: "Ready to use libraries" are the least of your problem. If you _need_ them, you're probably out of your league.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can send the codes to your compiler by uploading the code to server, compile it and then send back result / console output to browser screen.

For your information, PHP can execute shell commands (which can "order" your compiler to compile the codes).